# Google cloud platform: Install Nvidia driver in VM created from Deep Learning VM Image

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nvidia

I created a deep learning VM in GCP by using its Deep Learning VM image (at this link https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/). This VM has one GPU (Tesla T4). Its OS is Debian 9.xx

After the VM has been created successfully, I tried to SSH to it. It asked me to install Nvidia driver, I answer Y (yes). It tried to install the driver. However, for some reason, it could not download the driver from some public gcp storage and the driver was not installed.

//-----------
Here is the log:
Downloading driver and install from GCS location gs://nvidia-drivers-us-public/tesla/450.36.0
6/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.36.06.run
CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://nvidia-drivers-us-public/tesla/450.36.06/NVIDIA-Linux
-x86_64-450.36.06.run
Nvidia driver installed.
//-------------

Would you help give me some suggestions so that the driver can be downloaded from the above storage and the driver is installed.

Thanks for any help.

inewtechs

Answer (score 1):

Can you please describe which command did you employ for creating the machine?

Bear in mind that driver installation might take up to 5 minutes during VM provisioning as indicated [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/cli#creating_an_instance_with_one_or_more_gpus):

"It may take up to 5 minutes before your VM is fully provisioned. In this time, you will be unable to SSH into your machine. When the installation is complete, to guarantee that the driver installation was successful, you can SSH in and run nvidia-smi."